# Android Studio auto Import unavailable for classed in src/test dir

Tags: settings, android-studio-2.3, auto-import

As the title said, during usual development,if I type in **Activity**, then **android.app.Activity** will be imported automatically. But during unit test developing in **src/test** directory, function **auto import** comes to be unavailable.I have to press **Alt+Enter** again and again to import the classes.Is any setting to make this automatically? Or some other way to make it easy...

Answer (score 0):

Try do those actions:

- **Close** the Android Studio and open it again
- Reload your project, **clean the project** and build it again. This should ensure that all packages in your projects have been loaded
- Make sure that you do not have any graphic plugin that can affect your visual highlights code. I pass through it when i was using Material UI theme.
- Check if the Auto Import is switched on in your settings
- If you can see the red lamp in the left side of you code and click on it, you will see every wrong thing that the Android Studio can detect on your code, else maybe you are doing something wrong with your imports
- If you are using Kotlin, remenber to use the [Kotlin suport plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin)

Comment: None of the above takes effect for me. Note that in src/test , "auto import" has never been available but always performs well in src/main. That's the point. So I think it is mostly related to the directory.